# apple mac-o linker error react native 0.63

Tags: ios, macos, react-native

I have upgraded the reactnative from 0.61 to 0.63 using upgrade helper now I'm facing this issue while running react-native run-ios.

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> - BUILD FAILED *
>
> The following build commands failed:
> Ld /Users/sshah/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newapp-ggwouaubanbpyhgaxauunijgwgmj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/newapp.app/newapp
> normal x86_64 (1 failure).

Any possible solution to try.
Thanks